# SSDP M-search does not work for unicast - single IP

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, ssdp

SSDP M-search request for discovery works great for multicast address 239.255.255.250. However, I have a requirement to send this request to a specific IP. It does not work. As per the [UPnP architecture document](http://upnp.org/specs/arch/UPnP-arch-DeviceArchitecture-v1.1.pdf) unicast discover message is supported, with a small difference from the multicast message

The multi-cast message is 
`M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1
HOST:239.255.255.250:1900
MAN:ssdp:discover
ST:ssdp:all
MX:1`

Unicast message is similar - except that the multicast IP is changed to specific IP and MX:1 is removed (as per the specification - did not find any code sample for unicast discover m-search)

```py
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_TTL, 32)
msg = 'M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\r\nHOST:239.255.255.250:1900\r\nMAN:\"ssdp:discover\"\r\nST:ssdp:all\r\nMX:1\r\n\r\n'
s.sendto(msg.encode('utf-8'), ('239.255.255.250', 1900))
resp = s.recv(1024)
print (resp)
```

This works great. But the following doesn't - the recv() call times out

```py
sock_1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
msg = 'M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\r\nHOST:<specific ip>:1900\r\nMAN:\"ssdp:discover\"\r\nST:ssdp:all\r\n\r\n'
sock_1.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_TTL, 32)
sock_1.settimeout(30)
sock_1.sendto(msg.encode('utf-8'), ('<specific ip>', 1900))
resp = sock_1.recv(1024)
```

I have tried a few more variations of 'setsockopt' which did not work.
Please share if there are any clues for possible reasons - could it be from the device side that it responds to the multicast on 1900 but not to the unicast message?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: port can be different: check if there's a SEARCHPORT.UPNP.ORG header field in device notifys

Comment: There is no SEARCHPORT header in the device response to the multicast M-Search. Does it mean that the device is using the default port - 1900?

Comment: Tried ports 80 and 554. It didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

```
msg = 'M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\r\nHOST:<specific ip>:1900\r\nMAN:\"ssdp:discover\"\r\nST:ssdp:all\r\n'
```

You're missing a final `\r\n` in the end (it's for the empty line signaling end of headers: without it the receiver will just keep waiting for more).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But adding \r\n didn't help.

Comment: In my case this is completely opposite when i added \r\n it keep waiting.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference with a unicast m-search is the `HOST`, like you've got.

Are you binding the socket? It should be bound to port 0. Here's an example of setting up a socket for ssdp: https://github.com/lbryio/aioupnp/blob/master/aioupnp/protocols/multicast.py#L64

In addition to the final `\r\n` pointed out by Jussi, you may find you need to try different permutations of the M-SEARCH format, some gateways are very finicky. For some the value for `MAN` must be in quotes, for others it must not. Additional quirks are the order of `MAN`, `MX`, `ST` and the capitalization of `HOST`/`Host` and `MAN`/`Man` . You may also need to try a variety of search targets.

Comment: Is socket binding required for creating 'client' socket? I believe bind is for server side.The multicast discovery is working fine without bind.

Comment: Tried a few combinations of removing quotes, and using small case MAN/ST/HOST. It didn't help. Can we know specifics by any way for a particular device?